# ActionBar with small icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I use the ActionBar provided by android.support.v4 and until now, works really good. Now I install my app in android 4.3 and stop works.

It seems that in version 4.3, Android leaves the fixed width of the icon, and in addition, includes a padding which further reduces the icon size.

I use this code to make each Action:

```
android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(menu.add(0, 1003, 2, R.string.no_local)   .setIcon(R.drawable.nolocal),    MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

[image: Android Version 4.0.4]
Android 4.0.4

[image: Android Version 4.3]
Android 4.3

### What I need change to make my action bar in Android 4.3 looks like in Android 4.0.4?

Comment: check out this article you may get some idea ... http://www.creativefreedom.co.uk/icon-designers-blog/android-4-1-icon-size-guide-made-simple/

Comment: `I use the ActionBar provided by android.support.v4` **NO**. You are using **ActionBarCompat**, which comes from android support library **v7**

Comment: **NO**, I am using support library **v4**, as I said.
I am also using *MenuItemCompat*. 

I am **not** using this Action Bar: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the icon of my ActionBar to 32x32 px I said in:
http://www.creativefreedom.co.uk/icon-designers-blog/android-4-1-icon-size-guide-made-simple/